# How can I split my code, and keep it all asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've been coding just as a side project for a bit, piecing together bits that other people have written (it's for a simple discord bot). I want to split my code to make it easier to problem solve and read, however whenever I try to use the code it comes up with an error saying 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function'.

I've tried supposedly loading the code asynchronously, loading it with require() and then making a single command asynchronous, making the entire code in the file asynchronous (it's not just one command I want to load, but a whole file. Also I'm not sure if I tried it correctly or not), using the npm async-require, and maybe some others that have been around on the internet.

```
//one of the solutions I've tried. This is just copy pasted from the 
//answer

//file2.js
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function (callback) {
   fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
    callback(err, data);
  });
};

//file1.js
require('./passwords')(function (err, passwords) {
  // This code runs once the passwords have been loaded.
});
```

In the first file before I split it, I started it with `client.on('message', async message => {` and it made me able to use the `await` function in every command. I want to still be able to do that, but just have it a bit neater and easier to use by splitting it.

I'm trying to get this done so I can move on to a different question I asked and give one of the answers a tick. Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix those awaits so that they are not inside async functions. This is a lexical issue that can be solved just by looking at the location were the error occurs. Just look for the nearest containing function to where the await is and mark it async. Repeat until the error goes away.